# Harmon.ie Crashes Outlook

Tags: harmon.ie

I'm trying to install Harmon.ie on a new laptop.  I downloaded the latest version, it installs.  I run outlook 2013, I see the outlook splash screen and then the splash screen goes away immediately and outlook is not running.

The next time I run outlook it puts me in safe mode.  If I disable Harmon.ie, outlook runs fine.

Windows 8.1
Office 2013

I see this error in the event viewer
.NET Runtime version 2.0.50727.8009 - CLR: Fatal Execution Engine Error (00007FFDD17718DE) (80131506)

Do you have any tips on how to debug this error?

Regards,

Kris

Answer (score 1):

Seems to be a .net 2.x corrupted framework.
Please stop Outlook
Register the below registry key
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00
[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Mainsoft\Prefs\PreferredCLRVersion]
@="4.0"

PreferredCLRVersion is a subkey 
4.0 is the default value of this subkey

Start Outlook again.

---- Jean